# Arduino alternative for delays?

Tags: c++, arduino

What I wanted to do is to run 2 traffic lights simultaneously(ex. North and South).Is there an alternative for delay besides millis? I tried to use Blinkwithoutdelay but as a newbie its very complicated for me to use it.

```
    digitalWrite(greenled, HIGH); //Green on for 1 seconds
    delay(greenDuration);
    digitalWrite(greenled, LOW); //Green off, yellow on for 1 seconds
    digitalWrite(yellowled, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(yellowled, LOW); //yellow off, red on for 1 seconds
    digitalWrite(redled, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(redled, LOW); //Red off


    digitalWrite(greenled2, HIGH); //Green on for 1 seconds
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(greenled2, LOW); //Green off, yellow on for 1 seconds
    digitalWrite(yellowled2, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(yellowled2, LOW); //yellow off, red on for 1 seconds
    digitalWrite(redled2, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(redled2, LOW); //Red off
```

Complete code:

```
int beam = 2;//Beam sensor
int greenled = 4;
int redled = 7;
int yellowled = 13;
int greenDuration =1000;    //normal time
int greenShortDuration = 1000;
int greenIncrement = 5000; //5 seconds
void setup() 
{
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(greenled, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(redled, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(greenled, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(beam,INPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
            Serial.println("Status:low");
            digitalWrite(greenled, HIGH); //Green on for 5 seconds
            delay(greenDuration);
            digitalWrite(greenled, LOW); //Green off, yellow on for 2 seconds
            digitalWrite(yellowled, HIGH);
            delay(1000);
            digitalWrite(yellowled, LOW); //yellow off, red on for 5 seconds
            digitalWrite(redled, HIGH);
            delay(1000);
            digitalWrite(redled, LOW); //Red and Yellow off

    digitalWrite(greenled2, HIGH); //Green on for 1 seconds
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(greenled2, LOW); //Green off, yellow on for 1 seconds
    digitalWrite(yellowled2, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(yellowled2, LOW); //yellow off, red on for 1 seconds
    digitalWrite(redled2, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(redled2, LOW); //Red off
  if(digitalRead(beam)==HIGH){
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
      Serial.println(i);

      while(i>=10){
          Serial.println("Motion Detected");
          greenDuration +=greenIncrement; //Add 5 seconds everytime
          Serial.println(greenDuration);

        break;
      }

      }

    }
         if(!digitalRead(beam)==HIGH){
        Serial.println("hey"); //indication of code is working
        greenDuration=greenShortDuration;
        return;

}

}
```

Comment: Traffic lights is the most used example of a finite state machine. I suggest you to use a `uint8_t` variable to store the current state of the program (e.g. "green on", "green off, yellow on" and so on). You will have to encode them using numbers, e.g. `const uint8_t state_green_on = 1;` `const uint8_t state_green_off_yellow_on = 2` and so on. In this case, enums are better (if you don't know what they are don't worry, just give each state a meaningful name and a UNIQUE number). Once done, modify the BlinkWithoutDelay so that, every time it enters the if when the amount of time has passed,

Comment: the proper actions are executed and the state is advanced (for instance, if the current state is state_green_on, you will have to 1) set the current state to state_green_off_yellow_on; 2) set the green led to off; 3) set the yellow led to on. Do this for all the states, and you will have a program which does not block and executes everything. I suggest you to avoid finite state machines libraries because, in my opinion, you have to learn the basics and the limits of FSM before using ready-for-use code (and your example is the most trivial example of a FSM which can be implemented easily)

Comment: Please don't add "[FIXED]" or "[SOLVED]" to the title, and please don't include the answer in the body of the question. The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer. It's perfectly acceptable to post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use Blinkwithoutdelay but as a newbie its very complicated
>   for me to use it.

You have to try harder :)

Imagine loop() isn't the "program" but a description of any moment. 
In general it detects that neither time for a change nor a new pushbutton request has come, so loop exits immediately.
Even if something should have happened, any new reaction does not take any time, and loop exits immediately.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to solve the given traffic lights sample.

Instead of calling the delay function you could call your special delay-function:

```
int globalFlagSomeonePressedBeam = false;  // store global if someone pushed the beam button

void delay_and_check_for_beam (int msDelay) {
    for (int i=0; i<msDelay; ++i) {
        if(digitalRead(beam)==HIGH){ // check beam button
            globalFlagSomeonePressedBeam = true; // store information
        }
        delay(1);
    }
}
```

Between the calls to your delay function you set the right lights (digital outs)
After you check your globalFlagSomeonePressedBeam you need to set it back to false

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

```
unsigned long curGoStopDuration, defGoStopDuration = 5000, maxGoStopDuration = 30000;
unsigned long currentMillis;

#pragma region SensorFields
int durationIncrement = 2500;
unsigned long greenPrevMillis;
float DetectionTime = 2500;
bool triggered;
#pragma endregion

enum LightState { Green, Yellow, Red };

class Stoplight
{
private:
    int greenLed, yellowLed, redLed;
    unsigned long previousMillis;
    float CurInterval;
    LightState state;
public:
    unsigned long GreenDuration = 5000;
    unsigned long RedDuration = 5000;
    int YellowDuration = 1000;

    Stoplight(int gLed, int yLed, int rLed) :greenLed(gLed), yellowLed(yLed), redLed(rLed)
    {
        pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(yellowLed, OUTPUT);
    }

    void Loop()
    {
        if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= CurInterval)
        {
            previousMillis = currentMillis;
            //Transitions
            switch (state)          
            {
                case Green:             
                    ToYellow();
                    break;
                case Yellow:
                    ToRed();
                    break;
                case Red:
                    ToGreen();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    void ToGreen()
    {
        digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
        digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
        CurInterval = GreenDuration - YellowDuration;
        state = Green;
    }

    void ToYellow()
    {
        digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
        digitalWrite(yellowLed, HIGH);
        CurInterval = YellowDuration;
        state = Yellow;
    }

    void ToRed()
    {
        digitalWrite(yellowLed, LOW);
        digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
        CurInterval = RedDuration;
        state = Red;
    }

};

Stoplight SL_01(2, 3, 4), SL_02(5, 6, 7);
int beamSensor = 8;

void setup()
{
    //Set default values
    curGoStopDuration = defGoStopDuration;

    SL_01.ToGreen();
    SL_02.ToRed();

    pinMode(beamSensor, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    currentMillis = millis();
    Sensor();

    //Manipulate durations
    SL_01.GreenDuration = curGoStopDuration;
    SL_02.RedDuration = curGoStopDuration;
    SL_01.Loop();
    SL_02.Loop();
}

void Sensor()
{
    //If sensor detects something
    if (digitalRead(beamSensor) == HIGH)
    {
        if (!triggered)
        {
            greenPrevMillis = currentMillis;
            triggered = true;
        }

        if (currentMillis - greenPrevMillis >= DetectionTime)
        {

            if(curGoStopDuration < maxGoStopDuration)
                curGoStopDuration += durationIncrement; //Add seconds

            greenPrevMillis = currentMillis;

            Serial.print("Green light duration is now: ");
            Serial.println(curGoStopDuration);
        }
    }
    else  //No detection
    {
        curGoStopDuration = defGoStopDuration;
        triggered = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need interrupt on your beam, fast one, just counter, but its necessary for more precise counting (traffic =) )... this works for me just fine:

```
#define redPin1 40
#define yellowPin1 41
#define greenPin1 42
#define beamPin1 21
#define redDuration 1000
#define yellowDuration 1000
#define greenDuration 1000
#define durationIncrement 500

byte carCounter1 = 0;
byte state1 = 1;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(redPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(yellowPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(greenPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(beamPin1, INPUT);

    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(beamPin1), beamCount1, RISING);
}

void beamCount1()
{
     carCounter1++;
}

void wait(long duration)
{
    int wait = 0;
    long last = millis();
    while (wait == 0)
    {
        long now = millis();

        if (now - last >= duration) { wait = 1;}
        else {}
    }
}

void redLight(byte redLightPin)
{
    digitalWrite(redLightPin, HIGH);
    wait(redDuration);
    state1 = 2;
}

void yellowLight1(byte redLightPin, byte yellowLightPin)
{
    digitalWrite(yellowLightPin, HIGH);
    wait(yellowDuration);
    digitalWrite(redLightPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLightPin, LOW);
    state1 = 3;
}

void yellowLight2(byte yellowLightPin)
{
    digitalWrite(yellowLightPin, HIGH);
    wait(yellowDuration);
    digitalWrite(yellowLightPin, LOW);
    state1 = 1;
}

void greenLight(byte greenLightPin)
{
    digitalWrite(greenLightPin, HIGH);
    long incremented = greenDuration + (carCounter1 * durationIncrement);
    wait(incremented);
    digitalWrite(greenLightPin, LOW);
    carCounter1 = 0;
    state1 = 4;
}

void trafficLight(byte red, byte yellow, byte green)
{
    switch (state1){

    case 1: 
      redLight(red);
      break;
    case 2:
      yellowLight1(red, yellow);
      break;
    case 3:
      greenLight(green);
      break;
    case 4:
      yellowLight2(yellow);
      break;
    }
}

void loop()
{
    trafficLight(redPin1, yellowPin1, greenPin1);
}
```

no delays, just wait function which makes track of millis... if you want more precision, count the time needed for each light and remove it from wait...